# Is it possible to use variable in Spring property files?

Tags: spring

I have some properties in my config.properties file in spring like:

> adminip=182.178.22.21
>
> websiteurl=//182.178.22.21:4056/test

I want to use adminip in other properties in the same file (config.properties) as variable; some thing like this:

> adminip=182.178.22.21
>
> websiteurl=//${adminip}:4056/test

is it possible?
actually adminip is redundant in other properties.

Comment: config.properties is defined in dispatcher-servlet.xml like this:<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties"/>

Comment: you can not just define port=4056 url=test in properties file and in config when you want to replace use myUrl=${adminip}:${port}/${url} ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In spring-boot you can use placeholders like here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-placeholders-in-properties

So your porperty will be

```
adminip=182.178.22.21

websiteurl=${adminip}:4056/test
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible to do in `*.properties` file, but you could do adjustment to code and do smth like:

```
String adminip = ...;
 String websiteurl = String.format("//%s:4056/test", adminip);
```